# affine homeomorphisms between convex sets the same as homeomorphisms of extreme points?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $K_1, K_2$ be compact, convex subsets of some localconvex vectorspaces, $V_1,V_2$. They are also Choquet-Simplices and the set of extremepoints $\partial K_1,\partial K_2$ are metriziable. Now I know that every point $x\in K_i$ can be uniquely representet by a probability-measure $\mu_x$ on the set of extremes $\partial K_i$ by the relation
$$\lambda(x)=\int_{\partial K_i} \lambda(e)d\mu_x(e)$$
for all $\lambda:V_i\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ continous and linear. Every probability measure $\mu$ on $\partial K_i$ determines a point $x_{\mu}$ in the above way. For two topological spaces $T_1,T_2$ let $H(T_1,T_2)$ be the set of homeomorphisms from $T_1$ to $T_2$. A map $f:K_1\rightarrow K_2$ is called affine if $f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)=\alpha f(x)+(1-\alpha)f(y)$ holds for all $x,y\in K_1$ and $\alpha\in[0,1]$. Now I am interested in the relation of $H(\partial K_1,\partial K_2)$ and the set
$$A(K_1,K_2):=\{f\in H(K_1,K_2): f~\text{is affine}\}.$$
For every $f\in H(\partial K_1,\partial K_2)$ I define $f':K_1\mapsto K_2$ by 
$$x\mapsto \mu_x \mapsto \mu_x^f \mapsto x_{\mu_x^f}=:f'(x)\in K_2$$ 
Is $f'\in A(K_1,K_2)$? If so, is $f\mapsto f'$ bijective? I know that the inverse should be "restriction of a function to the set of extremes". 
If you can give an answer or give reference where i can find answer, i would be very happy :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is pretty clear - or I'm missing something.

The measure of a convex combinaton $\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y$ is the corresponding convex combination of measures, and this relation survives the application of $f$, hence $f'$ is indeed affine. It is also invertible as $(f')^{-1}=(f^{-1})'$. Thus we have indeed a map $H(\partial K_1,\partial K_2)\to A(K_1,K_2)$, $f\mapsto f'$. The would-be inverse is indeed $g\mapsto g|_{\partial K_1}$ (the restricted function necessarily being continuous) and it is at least immediately clear that this is a left inveres (i.e., $f'|_{\partial K_1}=f$). But it is also clear that an affine map is determined by its action on $\partial$, i.e., $(g|_{K_1})'=g$.